School basketball TV show (British, I think)
I'm searching for a TV series name, I guess the leading girl's called Holly and she started a basketball team called the Outlaws. In school they are rivals with a team called Ramz or Rams, I don't recall. Anyone know the name?

Sounds like Holly's Heroes from Australia that aired in 2005:

Holly McKenzie is a 14-year-old New Zealander who moves to the Australian seaside town of Woolich with her family. When her dreams of playing basketball with the local team the "Rams" are quickly shattered, Holly is determined to prove her ability by forming her own team, the "Outlaws".

Here's the intro:



